# displaying image on modelmesh with transparency

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

i have a modelmesh that has a image on it. When i draw the modelmesh i get the image but i also get a black bacground. The image is png and transparent and is added in 3ds max(i don't give it coordinates to be drawn, it sits on the modelmesh). How can i make the black background transparent?

Here is my drawing code:

```
 foreach (BasicEffect effect2 in modelMesh)
 {
     effect2.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
     effect2.LightingEnabled = true;
     effect2.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
     effect2.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix;
     effect2.View = camera.viewMatrix;
     effect2.World = transforms[modelMesh.ParentBone.Index] * gameobject.orientation;
     effect2.Alpha = 1;

  }
  modelMesh.Draw();
```

Comment: Can't you switch in property dialog of your model from Basic effect to AlphaTestEffect and also in foreach use AlphaTestEffect instead of BasicEffect?

Comment: there is a small problem. If i make the changes you said, i get this error:" ErrorThe mesh "s31", using AlphaTestEffect, contains geometry that is missing texture coordinates for channel 0." note that my images are not included in my model, i have them in my LibContent folder along with my model.

Comment: Ok. You can also try to set RenderState alpha blending to enabled: GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
GraphicsDevice.RenderState.SourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;

Comment: that looks to me as xna 3.1. i've used this: SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend; and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend; fixed the problem (XNA 4.0)